# Listening to text/event-stream using C#

Tags: c#, server-sent-events, event-stream

I am writing a C# class to wrap around a simple web service. The RESTful stuff was easy to wrap up, but now I need to raise an event when something on the server changes.

I've set the server up to make an event stream available, but I don't know how to pick up the stream in C#.

Currently I'm dong something like this:

```
public class ServiceWrapper
{
    private readonly wc = new WebClient();

    public ServiceWrapper()
    {
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(UriOfEvent));
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += ServerEventOccurs;
    }

    private void ServerEventOccurs(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(args.Result))
        {
            var message = ParseStream(sr);
            RaiseServerEventOccurred(message);
        }

        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(UriOfEvent));
    } 

    //usual code for declaring and raising ServerEventOccurred event
}
```

In my test the event gets picked up once, but not twice. The event on the server is essentially a switch - something happens and it goes on, something else happens and it goes off. I know the switching works, because I've hooked the event stream up to a normal web page to test it.

How should I be dealing with event streams in C#?

Edit 1: I've updated the code to fix the bug TimVK points out, but the event stream still isn't being picked up the second time it should be.

Comment: Embarrassingly it seems that my problem was with how my test worked. A couple of lines were in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't it work when you put your `wc` as a property in the class instead of creating always a new one in your methods?

```
public class ServiceWrapper 
{ 
    WebClient wc {get;set;}
    public ServiceWrapper() 
    { 
        wc = new WebClient(); 
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(UriOfEvent)); 
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += ServerEventOccurs; 
    } 
 
    private void ServerEventOccurs(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs args) 
    { 
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(args.Result)) 
        { 
            var message = ParseStream(sr); 
            RaiseServerEventOccurred(message); 
        } 
 
        wc = new WebClient(); 
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(UriOfEvent)); 
    }  
 
    //usual code for declaring and raising ServerEventOccurred event 
}
```

Then I suppose the event should be raised everytime.

Comment: I can't believe I've made such a rookie mistake. Of course I wouldn't be listening to the new webclient's events. Unfortunately this hasn't got to the root of the problem. The event is still only being received once. I'll update my question with new code.

Comment: Don't you need to add the line `wc.OpenReadCompleted += ServerEventOccurs;` to the ServerEventOccurs after the `new`? Because it is then newly declared? I can be wrong also but it is just my thought and I want to learn also through this site and trying to help answering.

Comment: Right, I used to, but now I just reuse the old object. I don't have the `wc = new Webclient();` line in the event handler anymore.

Comment: Hmm, ok, you're right. I didn't noticed that so that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebClient myWebRequest = null;
        String Path = "http://192.168.196.106/home/events/";
        Uri uri = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            uri = new Uri(Path);

            this.myWebRequest = new WebClient();
            this.myWebRequest.Headers.Set("Host", "192.168.196.106");

            this.myWebRequest.OpenReadCompleted += MyWebRequest_OpenReadCompleted;
        }

        private async void MyWebRequest_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var message = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine("message = {0}", (object)message);
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("WebException: {0}", (object)ex.Message);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("IOException: {0}", (object)ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", (object)ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myWebRequest.OpenReadAsync(uri);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myWebRequest.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).