# Post data to an API endpoint which is returning a server-sent event stream

Tags: c#, post, server-sent-events

I have an API endpoint, which is accepting a POST method, which is initiating a task in the background. While the task is running, it is responding with status updates.

I am currently stuck in finding a way to implement this in C#.

I am able to open a SSE endpoint similar to the answer here: [Listening to text/event-stream using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466595/listening-to-text-event-stream-using-c-sharp)
But as far as I can see, the `WebClient` class is not excepting a body when using `OpenReadAsync`.

I tried putting write and read after each other:

```
wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/event-stream");
wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
wc.OpenReadCompleted += ServerEventOccurs;
wc.UploadStringCompleted += ServerEventOccurs;
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URL + endpoint), JsonSerializer.Serialize(model));
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(Program.URL + endpoint));
```

but this results in an exception (as read and write are not possible at the same time).
When changing to `UploadString` it is waiting for the response and not triggering the `ServerEventOccurs` event.

Am I doing it completely wrong? I guess this is not an unsolvable task...

Comment: It is an unsolvable task :-) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285526/841830 You will have to do your POST upload, and your event source updates as two separate API endpoints.

Comment: @DarrenCook that's a pitty. Postman is actually able to handle that... maybe I find another way. But thank you for your answer.